# Fonts are not loading and not even including in build

Tags: fonts

//Webpack.config

```
 {
   test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/i,
            use: {
                loader: "file-loader",
                options: {
                  name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                  outputPath: 'fonts/'
                  
            }},
            type: 'asset/inline',
        }
```

This is my webpack.config file i have added this snippet but its not getting included in build

i have created a fonts folder inside src directory i want that fonts folder should include in my build and when i try to access any file i am getting 404 error i expect that files should be included in css as well in order to access the fonts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.